# Can I do a calculation using only the 2 numbers after decimal point in c++?

Tags: c++11, floating-point, decimal-point

**Example:**

I have a variable **A** that has a value of **5.123**.

**A * 2 = 10.246**

I want calculate with only the 2 numbers after the decimal point **(.12)**, like that:

**A * 2 = 10.24**

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You might need to use a fixed-point decimal library for this. You're not likely to get good results with floating point values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to truncate it:

```
value = (double) ((int)(value * 100))/100;
```

Here is a sample:

```
double valueOne = 2.34256;
cout<<valueOne<<endl;
double valueTwo = (double)((int)(valueOne*100))/100;
cout<<valueTwo<<endl;
```

Output:

```
2.34256
2.34
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how fancy you need to be with your numbers but the following strategy should work.

```
double A = 5.123;
int A1 = A*100;   // A1 is 512
int A2 = A1*2;    // A2 is 1024
A = 0.01*A2;      // A is 10.24
```